# Infinite List in Android

Tags: android, list

I want to create an infinite list , when i scroll to the end of list , my list will show first item, second item ... at the end() . Such as :

```
item[0]
........
item[last]
item[0]
item[1]
```

The first thing comes to my mind is that I will double the list so it can show like I wished.
Unfortunately , it's a bad idea because size of my list will grow more and more , and loading a big list is not good for performance(obviously). 
May you guys show me other solutions to handle this case ? Thank you very much .

Comment: Have you found a solution? And why don't you respond to the suggested variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RecyclerView`, you can achieve what you want in few steps. The idea is to set adapter's item count to infinity, and place your first item to the middle of infinity.

In your `Adapter` override `getItemCount()` method like this.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;// Not the infinity, but I'm not sure someone will scroll about 2 million items and find out that's a cheat
}
```

Then in the class where you use the `RecyclerView`, get `LayoutManager` and set starting position to the middle of adapter `itemCount`.

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = getLayoutManager();
    int pos = (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2); //Voila, you are in the middle of infinity
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(pos);
    yourAdapter.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

By doing this you are able to scroll your list in any direction up to about 2 000 000 scrolls, without container size increasing and any performance issues.

Comment: What is a recuclerView ? Is is RecyclerView , right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your list when user reach bottom of the page.
**You can keep track end of the page in on-scroll Listener.** 
Once user reach bottom of the or about to reach bottom of the page just double your list or extend it as per your requirement.
Extend or double your list is required because we need to store or display the data of each item in each row.
And Same thing happen in pagination concept.
Clearly understood we are not extending list unnecessary, we are extending when we really need.

You can visit this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) for Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews and RecyclerView.

Comment: " Extend or double your list is required" I got your idea but if i scroll more, such as : i scroll to the end of the list (list A) it will show the begin of new list (list B), and if i scroll more , i should remove list A to stop growing the list , is it true? )

Answer (score 0):

use onScrollListener() and when got to the end , use LIST.size()+VisibleItems (items from end of list that are visible) and put them first on array and renew your adapter data
sorry for very briefing Explanation !!!